# Making a div shake on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there anyway to make a div box shake on page load? Like maybe just once or twice?

***Update:* At this URL I have it still not working on page load, what am I doing wrong?
http://tinyurl.com/79azbav**

I think I'm stuck at the onpage load; that failure can be seen here:
[Get onpage to work correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042699/get-onpage-to-work-correctly)

I've also tried initiating the animation with my already implemented `body onLoad`:

```
<body onLoad="document.emvForm.EMAIL_FIELD.focus(); document.ready.entertext.shake();" >
```

*But still failing like a champ.*

Comment: Click refresh and smack your monitor! :)

Comment: @Louie thats my fallback for old IE =)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try something like this:

**EDIT**:
Changed `Shake()` to `shake()` for consistency with jQuery conventions.

```
jQuery.fn.shake = function() {
    this.each(function(i) {
        $(this).css({ "position": "relative" });
        for (var x = 1; x <= 3; x++) {
            $(this).animate({ left: -25 }, 10).animate({ left: 0 }, 50).animate({ left: 25 }, 10).animate({ left: 0 }, 50);
        }
    });
    return this;
}
```

**EDIT**:
In my example the `left` position is set to `25`, but you can reduce this for a more subtle effect or increase it for a more pronounced effect.

Using the `shake` function:

```
$("#div").shake();
```

Here's a jsFiddle that demonstrates it: http://jsfiddle.net/JppPG/3/

Comment: Thanks for the response, but where can I define which div this applies to?

Comment: @Truth: Thanks for demonstrating the implementation.

Comment: @LouieLouie: It's a jQuery function, so you can use it on any element on the page.

Comment: No, it's an actual function. I've updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JppPG/3/

Comment: Thanks for fiddle; it seems to working great on mouseclick, but I need on pageload.

Comment: @LouieLouie, James did all the hard work... surely you can handle a simple modification.

Comment: Just move it outside of the click event. It was just easier to demonstrate on click.

Comment: @LouieLouie: Don't forget to accept the answer if you're all set.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help; I'm still struggling with the onpage load aspect - I have it posted here 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042699/get-onpage-to-work-correctly'.

Answer (score 4):

Slight variation on @James-Johnson's excellent answer for ~shaking~ elements that are `absolute` positioned. This function grabs the current `left` position of the element and shakes it relative to this point. I've gone for a less violent shake, gas mark 10.

```
jQuery.fn.shake = function () {
    this.each(function (i) {
        var currentLeft = parseInt($(this).css("left"));
        for (var x = 1; x <= 8; x++) {            
            $(this).animate({ left: (currentLeft - 10) }, 10).animate({ left: currentLeft }, 50).animate({ left: (currentLeft + 10) }, 10).animate({ left: currentLeft }, 50);
        }
    });
    return this;
}
```