# Get onpage to work correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get this script to operate on pageload; I've tried `.ready` and `.load` and I still can't seem to get it working. I am using '`<body onLoad="document.emvForm.EMAIL_FIELD.focus()">`' in my site as well. But that shouldn't matter, right?

***Update:*** At this URL I have it still not working on page load, what am I doing wrong?
http://tinyurl.com/79azbav

Comment: Show the full HTML. The issue is very likely caused by your document structure.

Comment: did you tried both ready and load and not working I had this issue before is `body onLoad` working? then why not use body onload to run the whole function.

Comment: Body onLoad is working; it would be great to figure out how to use that for both places.

Comment: How could I incorporate the struggling function in body onLoad as well?

Comment: You missed the $ in  ("#entertext").shake();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The element with the id "entertext" probably doesn't had a native "ready" event.

You're probably thinking of this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#entertext").shake();
});
```

*With $ before* ("#entertext").shake();

Comment: So replacing with what was under 'return this;' with that, right? It still won't animate on page load, I know this can't be this hard. Thanks again James.

Comment: Is there anything I should be sure to define in the css of #entertext?

Comment: That should be a separate question.

Comment: This is already spawned into two questions; I added the #entertext styles above, hardly anything there.

Comment: Try adding a $ before ("#entertext").shake();