# move div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div and I am trying to move it right and left on page load using js to create a shaking movement.

My code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        obj = document.getElementById('hs');            
        obj.style.position='relative';  
        function goRight(){             
            obj.style.right = 10px;
            window.setTimeout(goLeft, 100);
        }
        function goLeft(){
            obj.style.left = 10px;
            window.setTimeout(goRight, 100);
        }
        window.onload =goRight;
    </script>
```

But it doesn't work. The id of my div is `hs`.

The html is:

```
            <div id="hs">
        <h1>hs</h1>
        <hr>
    </div><
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" ... classic.

Comment: have a look at `setTimeout` and `setInterval`.  You'll want to put some delay in there or this won't work.

Comment: You could refer to this: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041857/making-a-div-shake-on-page-load

Comment: james I added some delay but still

Comment: @citykid I don't see why this is bad in this case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/watson/MS8G9/)

```
obj = document.getElementById('hs');
obj.style.position='relative'; 

function shake(interval) {
    obj.style.right = '10px';
    setTimeout(function(){
        obj.style.right = '0px';
    }, interval);
}

setInterval(function(){
    shake(500);
}, 1000)
```

Your main issue was that after both the right and left values were set, you weren't changing anything anymore, it was static at `left: 10px; right: 10px;` you have to keep changing one of those values instead.

Comment: it makes perfect sense the way you implemented it. although there is still no progress...

Comment: what do you mean there is no progress?

Comment: it did not work. I might try it on another element in my html and see if the problem is somewhere else

Comment: I did. And I can see it works... I don't get what is wrong with it.. the div I just created for testing doesn't work either..

Comment: you probably need to wrap your code in $(document).ready(function(){...}) Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: I am using sublime to write my code... it doesn't display errors. i ll try to wrap it

Comment: the console in your browser.

Comment: it does actually! Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Comment: what is on the line # it references?

Comment: that one: obj.style.position='relative';

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40219/discussion-between-robert-sadler-and-user2917666)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the main problem, but you need to make the 10px into a string.

`obj.style.right = '10px';`

for both right and left.